# List network interfaces on a Ubuntu machine

Tags: networking, ubuntu, network-interface

How can I get a list of the network interfaces on a Ubuntu machine including wired and wireless?

Answer (score 3):

## ifconfig

1. Go to the terminal (Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)
2. Type `ifconfig` and press Enter.

This is analogous to `ipconfig /all` in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of network interfaces on a Ubuntu machine including wired and wireless, you can execute the following command in the shell.

```
$ip link or ip addr
```

ifconfig is obselete program. ip link and ip addr are replacement for ifconfig.